# Unicode Encode Error with greek letters when writing to a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am developing a customer application with Tkinter for GUI and inputs are all in Greek. I've made the program to write the inputs directly to a txt file, but when I fill the gaps with info about a customer in Greek and I click the button to save them, python gives me `UnicodeEncodeError`...only with Greek letters.

When I fill the gaps with latin characters all are fine, but I need Greek letters.

How can I solve this?

with open(saved + '.txt' , 'w') as file_open:

```
    file_open.write(saved_3 +'                         '+'PNC:'+saved_5+'\n')
    file_open.write(saved_1 +'\n')
    file_open.write(saved_2 +'\n')
    file_open.write(saved_3 +'\n')
    file_open.write(saved_4 +'\n')
    file_open.write(saved_6)



messagebox.showinfo('', 'ΕΠΙΤΥΧΗΣ ΑΠΟΘΗΚΕΥΣΗ ΣΤΟΙΧΕΙΩΝ')
```

Comment: Please, show the code which does not work. With the info you've given so far no one can help you. And... don't write all of your text in **bold**.

Comment: with open(saved + '.txt' , 'w') as file_open:
        
        file_open.write(saved_3 +'                         '+'PNC:'+saved_5+'\n')
        file_open.write(saved_1 +'\n')
        file_open.write(saved_2 +'\n')
        file_open.write(saved_3 +'\n')
        file_open.write(saved_4 +'\n')
        file_open.write(saved_6)


    
    messagebox.showinfo('', 'ΕΠΙΤΥΧΗΣ ΑΠΟΘΗΚΕΥΣΗ ΣΤΟΙΧΕΙΩΝ')

this part of code is the problem that writes the content of the variables that contain greek letters to txt file .

Comment: Edit that into the question (formatted as code), not in a comment.

Comment: Also, which Python 3.x? In 3.6, the default encoding should be UTF-8, which should be the same encoding you're using in your text editor, so everything should be fine, but with an old 3.x that may not be true. (You can test whether that's the problem—and fix it if it is—by just doing `… open(saved + '.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') …`)

Comment: Finally, please include the actual exception, with the traceback, instead of just describing it, so we can tell whether the error is happening in one of those `write` lines or that `showinfo` line or somewhere else entirely.

Comment: Thank you so much i read about that in so many topics but i didnt find actually that anwser , thank you ! <3 ... Problem fixed , i filled greek letters and all went perfectly